# Need Pagination Script For MVC

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I have Custom MVC and stuck on Pagination. Please give me code my MVC Structure is here. 
index->controller->model->back-to-controller->then-view.

Please help me out to create pagination to fit that MVC.

My Controller:

```
class Posts extends Controller{


public function __construct(){
    $this->postModel = $this->model('Post');
}

public function index(){
        $allpost         =       $this->postModel->getAllPosts();
       $data = [
            'posts'       =>      $allpost,
        ];
        $this->view('jobs/index', $data);}}
```

here is my Model:

```
class Post {
private  $db;
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new Database;
}
public function getAllPosts(){

    $this->db->query('select * from posts where active = 0 ');
    return $this->db->resultSet();
}
```

here is my View:

```
<?php foreach($data['allposts'] as $posts) : ?>
    <div class="jobContent">
        <div class="jobTitle">
           <h5><a href="="><?= $posts->title; ?></a></h5>
         </div>
         <div class="cName">
           <a href=""><?= $posts->des; ?></a>
          </div>
    </div>
 <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works. You can't just go about asking for code. We help you out when you're stuck on your own code. You haven't even tried to create any form of pagination by the looks of it. If you want to know how to start, then ask how.

Comment: I have tried lots of code but none of working. I know that is odd to ask it but i am stuck. Since 5 days i did try my own. I tied PHP i tried Ajax but exact view is not returning.

Comment: Then show us your attempts so we can help.

Comment: i have added the code would you please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datatables, it gives you the pagination and search functionality.

for example, you have your table like `<table id='sth'> </table>`, just add the following CDNs:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also :
 `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Then after that add this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sth').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajad, But i need to custom script not Datatable because i am using it as filter the products. Datatable gives only limited options.

Comment: Limited option for search? i think it can give you multiple search option with any column you desire! check these links:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html 
also: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Pagination{

protected $baseURL        = '';
protected $totalRows      = '';
protected $perPage        = 10;
protected $numLinks       = 2;
protected $currentPage    =  0;
protected $firstLink      = 'First';
protected $nextLink       = 'Next &raquo;';
protected $prevLink       = '&laquo; Prev';
protected $lastLink       = 'Last';
protected $fullTagOpen    = '<div class="pagination">';
protected $fullTagClose   = '</div>';
protected $firstTagOpen   = '';
protected $firstTagClose  = '&nbsp;';
protected $lastTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
protected $lastTagClose    = '';
protected $curTagOpen    = '&nbsp;<b>';
protected $curTagClose    = '</b>';
protected $nextTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
protected $nextTagClose    = '&nbsp;';
protected $prevTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
protected $prevTagClose    = '';
protected $numTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
protected $numTagClose    = '';
protected $showCount    = true;
protected $currentOffset= 0;
protected $queryStringSegment = 'page';

function __construct($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        $this->initialize($params);        
    }
}

function initialize($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        foreach ($params as $key => $val){
            if (isset($this->$key)){
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }        
    }
}

/**
 * Generate the pagination links
 */    
function createLinks(){ 
    // If total number of rows is zero, do not need to continue
    if ($this->totalRows == 0 OR $this->perPage == 0){
       return '';
    }
    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $numPages = ceil($this->totalRows / $this->perPage);
    // Is there only one page? will not need to continue
    if ($numPages == 1){
        if ($this->showCount){
            $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->totalRows;
            return $info;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }

    // Determine query string
    $query_string_sep = (strpos($this->baseURL, '?') === FALSE) ? '?page=' : '&amp;page=';
    $this->baseURL = $this->baseURL.$query_string_sep;

    // Determine the current page
    $this->currentPage = isset($_GET[$this->queryStringSegment])?$_GET[$this->queryStringSegment]:0;

    if (!is_numeric($this->currentPage) || $this->currentPage == 0){
        $this->currentPage = 1;
    }

    // Links content string variable
    $output = '';

    // Showing links notification
    if ($this->showCount){
       $currentOffset = ($this->currentPage > 1)?($this->currentPage - 1)*$this->perPage:$this->currentPage;
       $info = 'Showing ' . $currentOffset . ' to ' ;

       if( ($currentOffset + $this->perPage) <= $this->totalRows )
          $info .= $this->currentPage * $this->perPage;
       else
          $info .= $this->totalRows;

       $info .= ' of ' . $this->totalRows . ' | ';

       $output .= $info;
    }

    $this->numLinks = (int)$this->numLinks;

    // Is the page number beyond the result range? the last page will show
    if($this->currentPage > $this->totalRows){
        $this->currentPage = $numPages;
    }

    $uriPageNum = $this->currentPage;

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. 
    $start = (($this->currentPage - $this->numLinks) > 0) ? $this->currentPage - ($this->numLinks - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->currentPage + $this->numLinks) < $numPages) ? $this->currentPage + $this->numLinks : $numPages;

    // Render the "First" link
    if($this->currentPage > $this->numLinks){
        $firstPageURL = str_replace($query_string_sep,'',$this->baseURL);
        $output .= $this->firstTagOpen.'<a href="'.$firstPageURL.'">'.$this->firstLink.'</a>'.$this->firstTagClose;
    }
    // Render the "previous" link
    if($this->currentPage != 1){
        $i = ($uriPageNum - 1);
        if($i == 0) $i = '';
        $output .= $this->prevTagOpen.'<a href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->prevLink.'</a>'.$this->prevTagClose;
    }
    // Write the digit links
    for($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
        $i = $loop;
        if($i >= 1){
            if($this->currentPage == $loop){
                $output .= $this->curTagOpen.$loop.$this->curTagClose;
            }else{
                $output .= $this->numTagOpen.'<a href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->numTagClose;
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the "next" link
    if($this->currentPage < $numPages){
        $i = ($this->currentPage + 1);
        $output .= $this->nextTagOpen.'<a href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->nextLink.'</a>'.$this->nextTagClose;
    }
    // Render the "Last" link
    if(($this->currentPage + $this->numLinks) < $numPages){
        $i = $numPages;
        $output .= $this->lastTagOpen.'<a href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->lastLink.'</a>'.$this->lastTagClose;
    }
    // Remove double slashes
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);
    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->fullTagOpen.$output.$this->fullTagClose;

    return $output;        
}
```

}

and here code to index:

```
$baseURL = 'http://example.com/php_pagination/index.php';
$limit = 5;
$offset = !empty($_GET['page'])?(($_GET['page']-1)*$limit):0;

foreach($$data['allcount'] as $allcount){
$rowCount = $allcount->count;
}
$pagConfig = array(
'baseURL' => $baseURL,
'totalRows'=>$rowCount,
'perPage'=>$limit
);
$pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);

<div class="post-list">
<?php foreach($data['alljobs'] as $alljobs){
<?php echo $alljobs->job_title; ?>
} ?>
    <div class="list-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
<?php } ?>enter code here
```

by using that code i can get the pagination but record are not changing its shows same in all pages.